# Log error in Apps Script outside a try-catch block when accessing documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm currently working on a Google Apps Script whose purpose is to access files contained in a Google Drive folder and assign editing rights to a user on Google Sheets spreadsheets, including protected data ranges. To handle files that aren't spreadsheets, I've set up an error handling system with a try-catch block. However, despite the apparent smooth running of the script (as indicated by my last "Done" log), I encounter an error just before the end of the script execution which results in a failure.

Here are the execution logs, which clearly show the problem:

```
11:26:51 AM Notice  Execution started
11:26:58 AM Info    Done
11:26:59 AM Error   Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ''CORRECT-FILE-ID''.
```

The code fragment below illustrates the main function I use. Notably, the `giveAccessToAllFilesInFolder()` function is wrapped in a try-catch block, yet the error seems to occur outside these error-handling blocks. I've changed the file ID to protect it

```
function giveAccessScript() {
  try{
      Utility.giveAccessToAllFilesInFolder();
      Logger.log("Done");
  }catch (err) {
    Logger.log("Not happening : " + err.message);  
  }
}
```

I'm looking for advice on how to handle or avoid this error, so that the script can complete without failing when accessing and changing file permissions. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any ideas about the possible cause of this error and how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Best regards,
Amiel

Comment: After another attempt, the problem seems to be solved. I didn't remove the 'Log uncaught exceptions to Cloud logs' in the settings.